# What is the difference between "hot" and "active" questions?

Tags: support, questions, hot-questions, active

The two tabs have following tooltips

- **Active** : "Questions that have recent activity"
- **Hot** : Questions with recent interest and activity

They seem to display different questions with some common ground.

What is the exact difference between **hot** and **active** ?

Comment: These 2 tabs have always confused me and I wonder if they are both necessary?  I wonder if the SO team has any data on the popularity of these 2 tabs.  Are users generally using one and ignoring the other?

Comment: See also: [What Formula Should Be Used To Determine “hot” Questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602) and [How are “Hot” Questions Selected?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4766)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think Hot is taking into account a different measurement of the "velocity" of that question such as number of views, number of votes, and number of answers within a given time frame. Active questions are questions that have immediate activity on them (i.e. a question with a new answer is immediately bumped up).

Answer (score 7):

Active is based on creation / last modified time of any answer or the question itself.
So the recently changed questions or new ones are in the active list.

Hot seems to be a mix of how recent the question and how busy it is. (votes, answers, comments etc)

Answer (score 3):

hot = most activity

active = most recent activity