# How are questions in the 'hot' tab on a site selected?

Tags: support, questions, hot-questions

I know questions on the "hot" tab of a site homepage are based on some sort of views/velocity criteria, but **does anyone know the actual algorithm used**?

<sub>*Background: I was considering a feature-request about the "hot" tab, but I don't have enough information to speak about it intelligently.*</sub>

Comment: What hot questions? There are two kinds and for all we know they may share the same hotness formula or have two different formulae. One is the ["hot tab"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot) of each site, the other is the "pan-SE hot questions tab" in the "StackExchange" popup in the top-left of every page (which doesn't seem to have a URL but rather is only accessible by JavaScript).

Comment: This question referred to the 'hot' tab on Stack Exchange sites. This question was asked 2-1/2 years ago in July '09, when there *was* no pan-SE functionality. And, no, I don't know if they use the same algorithm or not.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

[What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)

> Based on my analysis of the above and the comments so far, here's the *second* version of what I have implemented so far. This might suck. I don't know:
>
> ```
> (log(Qviews)*4) + ((Qanswers * Qscore)/5) + sum(Ascores)
> --------------------------------------------------------
> ((QageInHours+1) - ((QageInHours - Qupdated)/2)) ^ 1.5
> ```
>
> Note that I do not weight an accepted answer very heavily. This is intentional, as I feel accepted answers are a fine social contract, but not necessarily a good data point for question or answer quality.

Keep in mind that this is **not** the formula used to determine the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) list (including the one on the [homepage sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209775/extend-the-new-hot-questions-sidebar)); see: [How do the “arbitrary hotness points” work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page/61343#61343)

Comment: Could you change the `log` to `log10` (logarithm to the base 10) or the equivalent in the language you've implemented it in? That will decrease the weighting given to question views by a factor of ~2.3 Right now it's heavily skewed towards more views than quality (votes)

Comment: Does this cover both the per-site hot list and the pan-SE hot list? the latter seems to take into account how young or small a site is, at least during beta.

Comment: I don't quite follow the quoitient. Doesn't that penalise recently updated questions? Or is that the point?

Comment: How would all of that criteria, ie views, score, updated, differ from the `activity` sort? How is sorting on `activity` different from sorting on `hot`... Is a "hot" question one that simply has a lot of activity over a short amount of time?

Comment: Is there any way to make a query in order to get the hot questions in the data explorer (http://data.stackexchange.com/)?