# How is the Hot/Active question algorithm implemented?

Tags: discussion, questions

How is the Hot/Active question algorithm implemented?

Is it based on the number of:

- Views
- Answers
- Votes
- Comments
- Something else

How did StackOverflow implement a reliable algorithm for this?

Answer (score 1):

Questions start out at the top of the 'Active' tab when they are first posted. A question will be "bumped" back to the top of the 'Active' tab whenever it receives a new answer, a tag is added or removed, or one of the questions/answers is edited.

The algorithm to determine 'Hot' questions is discussed here: [How are “Hot” Questions Selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected)

Answer (score 0):

I moved the Hot algorithm question here

[What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)