# Have votes tab show this week, this month, all time

Tags: feature-request, homepage, tabs

On the votes tab, What’s your favorite “programmer” cartoon? is always at number 1.

Perhaps consider having a list of top voted questions this week, this month, and all time?

Comment: Don't blame me - I tried to close and delete that question.

Answer (score 1):

> Perhaps consider having a list of top voted questions this week, this month, and all time?

You have described the primary tabs on the homepage. Use them!

Votes tab is really designed for use within specific tags, not so much the list of all questions. What's the highest voted [java]+[ndepend] post, for example?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make my suggestion clear. 'All' I have is newest, featured, hot, votes, and active :-) Hot and active don't match what I was after, according to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11596/how-is-the-hot-active-question-algorithm-implemented. But thanks for the advice about using the tags as well as the tabs...