# Question sorting

Tags: support

Newb question (sorry...) but I couldn't find a solid answer to this anywhere in the FAQ's...

What determines whether a question is categorized in the hot/activity/week&month lists (I know featured=bounty). Activity seems self-explanatory, but how is it differentiated from "hot," for example?

Also, is it possible to customize your experience on the site so that your home page only shows questions pertaining to a particular tag, or selection of tags?

Thanks again for your help! I'm very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Meta, @Zak!  Your question about hot vs. active has been asked before: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11596/how-is-the-hot-active-question-algorithm-implemented

Comment: As for your other question, see this FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-the-ignored-tags-and-interesting-tags-fields-on-the-user-prefs-page-do

Since your questions have been asked before, I'm going to vote to close your post; it's not a bad thing, it just helps to keep things organized.

Answer (score 1):

> What determines whether a question is
>   categorized in the
>   hot/activity/week&month lists (I know
>   featured=bounty). Activity seems
>   self-explanatory, but how is it
>   differentiated from "hot," for
>   example?

A formula is used to determine a hot question's ranking. See here: [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)

> Also, is it possible to customize your
>   experience on the site so that your
>   home page only shows questions
>   pertaining to a particular tag, or
>   selection of tags?

Yes! There is an interface on the right side that allows you to highlight questions with your "interesting" tags, and grey out (or hide -- see your user preferences in your profile) questions with your "ignored" tags.

You can add tags to either group in two ways: 1. enter the tag manually into the box and click the Add button, and 2. from a search result listing, if you hover over a tag on a question, you can add that tag to the appropriate group using the little popup menu that appears.

Comment: Also, if you hover over a tag (below a question) you will get an info box. You can click the "star" to toggle between ignored/favourite etc.