# Mechanics of questions being somehow "featured"

Tags: support

I am trying to understand the votes I am getting on [an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331686/why-and-not/7331721#7331721).
For some days now, I haven't gotten much votes on this answer, but in the last few hours, I got 13 votes out of nowhere.
I am trying to understand the mechanics behind this. Where is this question featured/displayed/whatever that makes people click on it and vote on it and the answers, although it is nearly a week old now? The question doesn't have an open bounty, so that can't be the reason...
And why does it happen in such "surges"?

Comment: Must be because it was C# and C# is where the golden showers happen

Comment: I think you are making fun of me, but anyway: Sorry, I don't understand :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Active" tab is the default view for stackoverflow.com/questions, and as Neal says one of the answers was edited:

> Questions start out at the top of the 'Active' tab when they are first posted. A question will be "bumped" back to the top of the 'Active' tab whenever it receives a new answer, a tag is added or removed, or one of the questions/answers is edited.

<sup>From [How is the Hot/Active question algorithm implemented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11596/how-is-the-hot-active-question-algorithm-implemented/11601#11601)</sup>

So when the question became active, lots of people saw it in the Active tab, and some of those who viewed it voted on your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my comment to Neal's answer...

Comment: Are comments also responsible for bumping a question back up?

Comment: @Daniel Hmm, that's odd. I wonder if it was linked/tweeted somewhere, or perhaps it was on the logged-out Interesting page.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the [answer right under yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331686/why-and-not/7336620#7336620) was edited 21 Hours ago so that could be it

So when users saw that that question was bumped 21 hours ago, they saw your answer and voted it up as well.

Comment: Hm... I don't know. The votes started rolling in only 3.5 hours ago. And since then I got a vote every few minutes... That doesn't look like it is the "Active" tab.

Comment: @Daniel -- also it could do with the time of day. It could be that type of question has a niche of people who go on SO at a certain time in the day and that happened to be the time that you got the upvotes.

Comment: It could also depend on the question being part of this week's newsletter...

Comment: @Bo Persson: Thanks. That sounds reasonable, too.