# Why are there 403,517 "hottest" questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, hot-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are “Hot” Questions Selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected)

If you click the `hottest` tab, you get:

[image: hottest]

If you click the `newest` tab, you get:

[image: newest]

So, what are the 2058 questions that are not hot?

Comment: Cool? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected

Comment: What's the flower for?

Comment: Disable your ad blocker and you will see, random ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal -- the hot algorithm rules out posts below a certain vote threshold.