# In the new StackExchange popup menu, what is the number to the left of hot questions?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-button

To the left side of questions listed under *Hot questions*, I see a number.

[image: screenshot]

What is that number? I would think it is the number of users who seen the question, but it's not the same number I see in the Q&A site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are "hotness" points.  You can see how they're calculated [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) and how they're tweaked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page).

Comment: Why would such a cryptic, semi-obfuscated statistic have such prominent visual and hierarchical placement?