# What does the number in the hot questions signify?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, hot-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In the new StackExchange popup menu, what is the number to the left of hot questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61793/in-the-new-stackexchange-popup-menu-what-is-the-number-to-the-left-of-hot-quest)

What does the number against the questions signigfy in the drop down on the top left corner of each page i.e. on pressing the stackexchange menu ?

And how is it calculated? I don't see it as the total number of votes on the question.

Screenshot for clarity:

[image: question score]

Comment: It is a measure of the question's hotness.

Comment: Looks like what you want is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected?rq=1).