# StackExchange box of Hot Questions hotness points

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

`Hot Question` list have a list on number associated with each question.

[Those are "hotness" points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61793/in-the-new-stackexchange-popup-menu-what-is-the-number-to-the-left-of-hot-quest). There should be tooltip what it is representing for. As it is really confusing showing only number there without any details.

> [image: number]

Comment: The first answer to the question you linked to points [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) for the calculation details.

Comment: @Oded this question sounds like a feature request to add them to the tooltip to me.

Comment: yes!!! it is feature request.

Comment: Don't worry @ZaheerAhmed, the points don't matter and they make no sense anyways. They're about as useful as `rand()`.

Answer (score 3):

Given that this number represents the abstract concept of hotness I would propose simply putting °C after the number. This makes it immediately obvious that its not question upvotes (which I initially thought it was) but is an "idea" of temperature. This could be complimented by a tooltip.

The one issue that might exist is one of location. As I understand it Celcius is used almost universally with the notable exceptions of the [United States, Belize and Palau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celsius#Worldwide_adoption) where Fahrenheit is used instead.

Comment: I believe the units are actually Unicorns per Fortnight (and before you ask for clarification, these are clearly Imperial Unicorns...which should not be confused with metric Unicorns).