# How is the hotness of a question determined on stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do the “arbitrary hotness points” work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page)

https://stackexchange.com/ has a very good listing of all the current "hot" questions?

**How is the hotness of a question determined?** Does it depend on the number of views, upvotes, answers, all of them?

I thought this question would have been asked before, but can't find it on meta.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page