# What do the numbers beside the global inbox hot questions mean?

Tags: discussion, global-inbox, stack-exchange-button

[image: This]

I can't find any reference to the number 79 in the actual [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9812). So, what does it mean?

Comment: It's the "hotness".

Comment: @KennyTM, what does that mean though? Doesn't the ordering of the questions kind of already tell you which questions are the hottest? I don't see a random number beside the questions on http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page

Comment: @KennyTM, ah okay. That makes sense, I haven't visited the StackExchange site in quite awhile. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the hotness index

You can see it also [here](https://stackexchange.com/questions/custom) (where it's labeled)

[image]

Comment: I haven't visited SE for awhile, I've never noticed that before. Thanks. Although now I notice a rounding discrepancy between the Global Inbox and main SE site :P

Comment: @Brandon, caching most likely