# Why did this question appear on the Hot Network Questions list?

Tags: discussion, bug, hot-questions, merged-questions

I saw [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80029/why-didnt-snape-keep-or-secure-his-copy-of-advanced-potion-making) in the Hot Questions list, but when I clicked it I saw that it was a question I had seen a long time ago. All the time stamps on the comments and answers are from a previous date, however at the right of the questions it says it was asked today and has only around 80 views, while if I remember correctly this question was asked around a year ago and had at least 1000 views

What happened here?

Comment: [Another question was merged into it.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/80029/revisions)

Comment: does this reset the number of upvotes in the original question as well?

Comment: high voted answer posted [several months ago (Apr 30 '14)](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/55312) pumps up hotness score, funny. Granted, merges aren't that frequent but when it happens, it looks really weird. [Is it possible for an old question to get on the hot questions list?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115345/165773)