# Was this epic answer from Scifi & Fantasy SE manually added to the Hot Network Questions?

Tags: support, hot-questions

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277345/321647) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115345/321647) answer, it becomes exceedingly difficult/impossible for a question to hit the HNQ once it gets older.

When this [legendary answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105743/64504) appeared on Science Fiction & Fantasy SE, it was over four years after the question had originally been asked. In spite of the epicness of the answer and overwhelming response (possibly the best ever on that SE), it should have been totally impossible for the question/answer to hit the HNQ, since the HNQ formula [divides by a product of the age of the question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/321647)

However, SF&F SE moderator Rand al'Thor [says this question was indeed in the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277358/321647) due to the epic answer.

Rand notes [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster#comment247725_105743) by [another user:](https://stackexchange.com/users/4784285/engineer-toast?tab=accounts)

> I thought of the story as soon as I saw the post in hot network
> questions. Now I am lamenting not having seen it in the unanswered
> section.

The user has [since clarified:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283893/was-this-epic-answer-from-scifi-fantasy-se-manually-added-to-the-hot-network-q?noredirect=1#comment920353_283893)

> Here's the data I can provide: When I saw the question in HNQ, I was
> on Win7 and using Internet Explorer 11 (only browser allowed on work
> computer at the time). I saw the question in the HNQ section on the
> right-hand side. At the moment, that section looks [like
> this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBuy2.png) for me. It's right
> underneath the Linked and Related questions lists. I was probably on
> either Puzzling or SuperUser since those are the two I frequent the
> most. I was definitely not on the root [SE](https://stackexchange.com/)
> site.

So:

1. Was this question really in the HNQ *after* the answer was posted?
2. If yes, was it manually added* to celebrate the epic answer?
3. If yes to #1 but no to #2, how was it possible?

I have tried to [use The Wayback Machine to research this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279509/321647), but the records seem incomplete for the relevant time period. The problem seems to be that the the second, third, fourth page etc. of the front page aren't cached frequently enough to give detailed results. I've also gotten [this weird message](http://web.archive.org/web/20151023071226/https://stackexchange.com/?page=3) saying "No questions found", further complicating research.

* = I have never heard of a question being *manually* added to the HNQ, but if this question was actually there after the answer, I can't really think of any other explanation. Unless I have misunderstood the math somehow.

Comment: The updated date may have helped it?

Comment: @Pureferret You mean the age of answers may be taken into account? That wouldn't be a bad idea. It would be cool to use the HNQ to advertise late, epic answers.

Comment: It could be, as Nathaniel mentioned in the comments [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277344/can-an-old-question-ever-resurge-as-a-hot-network-question/277358?noredirect=1#comment898566_277358), that Engineer Toast was confused between two different meanings of 'hot'?

Comment: @randal'thor Yeah, it sounds possible. I wonder, isn't there some way to confirm/deny? Doesn't SE keep a record of which questions were ever HNQ?

Comment: Here's the data I can provide: When I saw the question in HNQ, I was on Win7 and using Internet Explorer 11 (only browser allowed on work computer at the time). I saw the question in the HNQ section on the right-hand side. At the moment, that section looks [like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HBuy2.png) for me. It's right underneath the Linked and Related questions lists. I was probably on either Puzzling or SuperUser since those are the two I frequent the most. I was definitely not on the root [SE](http://stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: @EngineerToast Much appreciated, added to OP.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other information to provide, I don't pay much attention to the HNQ.

Comment: For what it's worth, I had no idea my comment would spark such a discussion and I had no idea about what was the math behind HNQ. After reading [Jeff Atwood's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/286319) regarding the formula - and I assume he might know a thing or two about how it works - I am even more confused. If `Qupdated` is the number of hours ago it was updated and `Qageinhours` is the time since OP, then I can't see how it could have ever scored as Hot under normal condition.

Comment: @EngineerToast Yes, this is exactly how I feel about this mystery.

Comment: @KyleHale Thanks for stopping by anyway :)

Comment: @EngineerToast The formula in that answer doesn't apply to the hot network questions list; it is for the [hot tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot) of individual sites.