# Is there any way to find questions that have been hot for a long time?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

I have noticed that [the following question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/25684/6415) has been among the hot questions of all SE sites during the last ten days. To me, this is an indication that this question should be really appealing (though in this particular case it is not that interesting to me!). So, just out of curiosity, is there any way to find similar questions that have once been hot for a long time?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Note that it could be that that question is hot *now* but wasn't so hot 10 days ago. Judging by the [post timeline](http://security.stackexchange.com/posts/25684/timeline) this one *has* been hot for 10 days though!

Comment: As for what makes an post 'hot', see [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think it's possible for an unnoticed post to suddenly become hot after ten days!

Comment: @MartijnPieters How do you access a posts timeline?

Comment: @Dynamic: add `/timeline` to the `questions/01245` part of the URL. Or use a [user script to add a link](http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a).

Comment: related: [Does Stack Exchange record when particular question enters and leaves hot list?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238445/165773) _'The difference is that... current request is limited strictly to "timeline of changes in a list of 100 elements", possibly recorded "once in an hour or two or... at least once a day'_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't, because we don't keep a history of view counts - a crucial piece of the hotness algorithm (itself a point in time calculation where age is a power factor).

In short: having a history of this would be difficult at best, but currently impossible since a view count history isn't stored.

Comment: However, it wouldn't be hard to store the information about the questions that have landed in hot section. That information must be already at least cached.

Comment: @ŁukaszL. cached in memory somewhere is totally different from in a database, it's a big ask for not much gain.

Comment: FWIW, [comment above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160893/is-there-any-way-to-find-questions-that-have-been-hot-for-a-long-time/160908#comment781494_160893) refers somewhat similar (probably less ambitious?) request which, however, doesn't involve tracking / history of vote counts in any way

Comment: Note that the view count [doesn't appear in the formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/295232) anymore. Right now, the only thing that prevents us from calculating the score from SEDE is the granularity of the vote dates.