# Which sites appear most often in the Hot Network Questions list?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, statistics, data-analysis

Is there any data about which Stack Exchange sites have their questions end up in the Hot Network Questions list the most? In particular:

1. What percentage of hot network questions comes from each site?

   1. What about all-time, this year, this month?
2. What percentage of questions from each site end up in the list? (It seems that a high percentage of all CodeGolf.SE questions end up here.)
3. Which site's questions stay on the list the longest?

And so on. Is there any data on these and similar questions?

Comment: [View count is not stored historically, so there are no stats on past entries to this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160908/209637).

Comment: related (not a duplicate): [Prevent specific sites from being overrepresented in the hot questions list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171551/165773). In brief, hot list is designed to work well only for Stack Overflow, with its 17 moderators, 2,000 trusted users, ~20,000 close voters and ~30,000 low quality post reviewers, who are up and ready to _permanently_ track, maintain and curate highly exposed content. SO being essentially immune to troublesome / destabilizing upvotes from ["association bonus powered"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183109/165773) outsiders doesn't hurt either

Comment: ...smaller sites, lacking moderation powers of SO scale, are essentially doomed to suffer from effects of [fake popularity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192046/165773 "'When votes of 20... 30... 100 users clearly indicate that only one or two answers are popular, it does not make sense to pretend that other answers are popular too...'"). SE team doesn't bother to at least [approximate addressing this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224750/165773 "Make hot questions with multiple answers age away faster on smaller / subjective-ish sites")

Comment: Purely anecdotal, but to me it seems like Arqade and Math are the most common.

Comment: @kevin how many Arqade titles have you seen?

Comment: related: [Does Stack Exchange record when particular question enters and leaves hot list?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238445/165773)

Answer (score 43):

It's about time for an update to this; the last one was from before some [major changes to the Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325060/295232) and the world has changed a lot in the past year. This time, I'll be looking at data from **April 2020 up to March 2021**; see the revision history for [August 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/315017/1) and [August – December 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/315017/2).

Stack Exchange itself only registers (since [February 2019](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/324643/295232)) the moment a question hits the Hot Network Question list, not when it disappears (unless a ♦ moderator removes it manually). I have some additional data (including scores and views) from August 2018 onwards, which has been collected into a PostgreSQL database which can be found [here](https://github.com/Glorfindel83/SE-Userscripts/tree/master/hnq-research). The main information is in the `snapshots` table, which is just the list of 100 Hot Network Questions downloaded every 10 (later 3) minutes.

Note that some external events might cause a spike in a site's popularity; e.g. I remember that during the [Falcon Heavy test flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falcon_Heavy_test_flight), the number of HNQs from [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com) skyrocketed (pun intended).

> 1. What percentage of hot questions comes from each site?

During this period, 4.76% of the Hot Network Question spots was composed of [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com), followed by [Role-Playing Games](https://rpg.stackexchange.com) with 4.06% and [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com) with 3.88%. The top 3 is unchanged since the [initial report period in August 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/315017/1), but the percentages have dropped significantly (presumably because of the limit of 5 questions per site which was introduced in 2019).

| Rank | Site | % of HNQ spots | # of (distinct) HNQs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Worldbuilding | 4.76 | 1515 |
| 2 | Role-playing Games | 4.06 | 1820 |
| 3 | Academia | 3.88 | 934 |
| 4 | Physics | 3.52 | 1433 |
| 5 | Science Fiction & Fantasy | 3.50 | 1331 |
| 6 | Code Golf | 3.14 | 586 |
| 7 | Electrical Engineering | 2.79 | 1459 |
| 8 | Politics | 2.78 | 662 |
| 9 | Puzzling | 2.62 | 1433 |
| 10 | Home Improvement | 2.29 | 969 |

<sub>Note that the number of HNQs is slightly different from the one in the next list (generated by SEDE) because of two things: 1) my script missed about two days in this period. This is less than 1% of the total period so I don't think it has much influence. 2) questions which entered the list *before* 2020-04-01 but were still in it on 2020-04-01 don't appear in the SEDE query. Again, not much influence I hope.</sub>

> 2. What percentage of questions from each site end up in the list?

You were right, almost half of the [Code Golf & Coding Challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com) questions become a Hot Network Question. The site is closely followed by [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com). The top 2 is the same [as in 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/315017/2) but percentages are slightly higher. This can now be answered with a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1402159/number-and-of-new-hot-network-questions-during-a-certain-period?fromDate=2020-04-01&tillDate=2021-04-01):

| Rank | Site | % of questions that hit HNQ | # of HNQs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Code Golf | 46.67 | 582 |
| 2 | Retrocomputing | 44.09 | 522 |
| 3 | Latin Language | 40.02 | 329 |
| 4 | Role-playing Games | 38.58 | 1834 |
| 5 | Puzzling | 38.56 | 1442 |
| 6 | Chess | 35.40 | 496 |
| 7 | Bricks | 34.39 | 195 |
| 8 | Worldbuilding | 30.64 | 1528 |
| 9 | Operations Research | 29.87 | 302 |
| 10 | Bicycles | 28.70 | 729 |

> 3. Which site's questions stay on the list the longest?

The winner here (in this time period) is [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com), but I suspect the results here can rather fluctuate between time periods (though they were the winner [in 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/315017/2) as well). Their 71 HNQs were (on average) 'hot' for a period of well over 2 days. This is a lot less than in 2018, because there's a hard limit of 3 days now.

| Rank | Site | Average time (hours) | # of HNQs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Parenting | 57.91 | 71 |
| 2 | Skeptics | 52.27 | 142 |
| 3 | Code Golf | 46.55 | 586 |
| 4 | Information Security | 40.57 | 322 |
| 5 | The Great Outdoors | 38.84 | 44 |
| 6 | Movies & TV | 38.38 | 153 |
| 7 | User Experience | 36.95 | 82 |
| 8 | Politics | 36.48 | 662 |
| 9 | Freelancing | 36.45 | 2 |
| 10 | Academia | 36.13 | 934 |