# Can a user have more than one "Hot Network Question” (HNQ) concurrently on one given SE site?

Tags: discussion, support, hot-questions

I wonder whether a user may have more than one "Hot Network Question” (HNQ) concurrently on one given SE site (i.e., >1 questions posted by the same user are HNQ at the same time in the same SE site).

Comment: Given we don't care about users but about content I would say yes.

Comment: Per site or network-wide?

Comment: @rene per site. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Yes. The algorithm is ignorant of question authors. According to my [script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315017/295232), on March 31st this year at 1:06am UTC, these two Travel.SE questions posted by the same author (guess who) were present in the Hot Network Questions list:

- [Why do flights sometimes share the same flight numbers?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/163124/28333)
- [Can I use a personal satellite phone/Internet connection as a passenger in a plane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/163094/28333)

Comment: Wow, what a coincidence!

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

If we study the answer from David Fullerton on [What are the criteria for questions to be selected for Hot Network Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756)
we find the following exclusion rules for hot questions:

> - Questions with no answers
> - Closed questions
> - Questions less than eight hours or more than 30 days old
> - Questions that were already selected to appear on the list more than 72 hours ago
> - Questions whose titles match a list of blocked keywords
> - Questions whose titles contain MathJax markup
> - Questions that a local moderator has manually removed from the list
> - Questions on per-site metas, Meta Stack Exchange, Stack Apps, and non-English sites

None of those rules mention users. We don't care about those.