# How to get the hot questions by some query?

Tags: support, hot-questions

Since [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected/4789#comment820038_4789) didn't receive any response, I decided to ask this.

I wanna get all the hot questions by some query, but I don't know how to do this. Even though I found out how this hotness algorithm works [here] [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected), I still don't know how to get these questions neither by some query in [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) nor using the API.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Hot questions, being transient, aren't included in the data explorer. To the best of my knowledge, they also aren't exposed in the API, so you'll probably have to scrape http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot.

Comment: related: [How can I get a HOT network questions week digest?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239310/165773)