# robots.txt was changed to block saving hot questions page in Wayback Machine, why?

Tags: support, hot-questions, robots, archive

Until yesterday it was possible to save hot questions page in Wayback Machine as discussed eg [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287809/165773).

Today [robots.txt](https://stackexchange.com/robots.txt) appears to be changed to block this.

I wonder what could be reasons for such a change?

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOHCQ.png]

---

In case if it matters, current contents of robots.txt file is as follows:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /feeds/
Disallow: /users/login/
Disallow: /users/chat-login/
Disallow: /users/logout/
Disallow: /users/authenticate/
Disallow: /users/flair/
Disallow: /api/
Disallow: /*/ivc/*
Disallow: /*?
Disallow: /leagues/*/week/*/20
Disallow: /leagues/*/month/*/20
Disallow: /leagues/*/quarter/*/20
Disallow: /leagues/*/year/*/20
Disallow: /leagues/*/alltime/*/20
Disallow: /filters/*/*
Allow: /

# for "/*?", refer to http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40360

#
# beware, the sections below WILL NOT INHERIT from the above!
# http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40360
#

#
# disallow adsense bot, as we no longer do adsense.
#
User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Disallow: / 

User-agent: Spinn3r
Disallow: /

#
# Yahoo Pipes is for feeds not web pages.
#
User-agent: Yahoo Pipes 1.0
Disallow: /

#
# This isn't really an image
#
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /*/ivc/*

#
# KSCrawler - we don't need help from you
#
User-agent: KSCrawler
Disallow: /
```

Comment: side note for those interested in maintaining historical log of HNQ at Wayback Machine, this page still can be saved over there if you enter Stack Exchange homepage URL `https://stackexchange.com` (which redirects to `questions?tab=hot`)

Comment: Guess they want to make it harder for people to archive it, thus making it harder to complain about them.

Comment: ["a tool to feed speculation and paranoia..."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238445/add-an-audit-log-to-record-when-particular-question-enters-and-leaves-hot-list#comment781671_238531) @ShadowWizard :)

Comment: I'm a little confused here - that file hasn't changed since May 2015 and the line in question has been there since 2010...

Comment: Maybe WBM adjusted their spiders? (Clearly part of the great HNQ conspiracy...)

Comment: and... https://blog.archive.org/2017/04/17/robots-txt-meant-for-search-engines-dont-work-well-for-web-archives/ internet archives might be ignoring robots.txt in future. Which should probably make you very happy

Comment: Any explanation as to what the KSCrawler comment is about?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> robots.txt was changed to block saving hot questions page in Wayback Machine, why?

Nope! The robots.txt hasn't changed since May, 2015. And the `Disallow: /*?` directive has been there since the file was created in 2010.

So...this wasn't us. The Wayback Machine changed something on their end.

Answer (score 4):

The answer appears to be hidden in the robots.txt file itself.

> Disallow: /*?

Seems to be the appropriate rule

and is documented in a comment

> # for "/*?", refer to http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=40360

Which might not be the right link. Dang, I was hoping that it would document itself

The line *incidentally* also prevents scrapers from accidentally running queries for almost any tab or search type thing which might be the actual reason. Its a lot simpler than a dozen seperate per-tab-type rules. Of course, we'd need a dev for a definitive answer but this seems plausible. [According to Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294762/robots-txt-was-changed-to-block-saving-hot-questions-page-in-wayback-machine-wh/294764#comment956454_294762), the files  haven't actually been changed recently - with the line being there since 2010, so *If* that's changed, it might be at wayback machine's end.

Comment: wonder why they decided to change to this way so suddenly (until yesterday [access went just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTt4W.png "as one can see at screen shot from linked question"))

Comment: Beats me, I don't exactly hang around watching the HNQ list all the time ;)

Comment: You can see on main sites ([e.g. MSE's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/robots.txt)) there are lots of separate rules  with "?" query strings; I guess having a single catch-all rule is a bit easier.. you generally don't want different tabs indexed I guess

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking. Also makes it more maintainable.

Comment: "To block access to all URLs that include question marks (?). For example, the sample code blocks URLs that begin with your domain name, followed by any string, followed by a question mark, and ending with any string:
 

User-agent: Googlebot

Disallow: /*?" Check the "Block URLs with robots.txt" section, "Pattern-matching rules to streamline your robots.txt code" subsection.