# Badge Request: Hotshot (Ask a Hot Network Question)

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request, hot-questions

I would like to suggest a <s>silver</s> [bronze](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298861/badge-request-hotshot-ask-a-hot-network-question?noredirect=1#comment971490_298861) badge which would be awarded for having a question featured as a [Hot Network Question](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot).

[image: Hotshot badge]

Currently there is [no way of tracking a user's Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294908/351462). There is no notification for users when their post is featured<sup>([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294907/should-we-be-notified-if-we-make-it-onto-hnq))</sup>, no audit log to record when a post is featured<sup>([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238445/add-an-audit-log-to-record-when-particular-question-enters-and-leaves-hot-list?noredirect=1&lq=1))</sup>, and no way of identifying which posts were previously featured<sup>([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271213/how-to-see-if-a-question-was-a-hot-network-question))</sup>.

While it may be a bit difficult to implement, a HNQ badge would at least provide some basic form of tracking for featured questions.

## Pros

- Notifies user when they make the list of Hot Network Questions<sup>[1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294907/should-we-be-notified-if-we-make-it-onto-hnq)</sup>
- Provides a way to track previously featured Hot Network Questions<sup>[2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271213/how-to-see-if-a-question-was-a-hot-network-question),[3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286986/please-open-the-hot-network-questions-to-auditing-via-the-data-explorer),[4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294762/robots-txt-was-changed-to-block-saving-hot-questions-page-in-wayback-machine-wh)</sup>
- Lets users know why their post is gaining a large amount of attention
- Gives positive encouragement for well-asked questions

## Cons

- Difficult or impossible to retroactively award to previously featured questions.

Comment: Silver is too much. Bronze is just enough for such a badge. It usually takes less than 5 minutes to post HNQ, from personal experience.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Adjusted to bronze per your suggestion.

Comment: The resultant Rep Capping is not enough reward for you? :)

Comment: I don't know that your last "pro" point really applies. There are a lot of crappy questions that hit the HNQ.

Comment: This badge would be almost equivalent to getting a Popular Question badge within 24 hours of posting.

Comment: if the question gets closed, would the system keep the badge like it happens with most or retract it like it does with tag badges? Badges are assumed to encourage desirable behavior ([which is not always the case with HNQ](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4415/168 "example discussed here"))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best approach for having a question featured in the *Hot Network Question* section is just making the asker more aware that it is there when it shows up. They often change frequently (*from what I've seen*) so it's not up there for long anyway. Perhaps a notification that states it's in the HNQ sidebar but apart from that, a badge doesn't seem necessary.

My thoughts on this are mainly due to the fact that getting placed there is semi-random (ish). It's somewhat based on popularity but simply having a super popular question doesn't seem to land you there all the time. Additionally, the amount of views you'd get from being on there is a sure fire way to get you reputation points and other badges based on how users interact with the question which should be enough of a reward.

At the moment badges have a set amount of steps on how to achieve them and trying to get onto the HNQ sidebar isn't exactly easy and something you can do with a definitive step by step. For example, you don't get there by getting *`x` amount of views* and *`y` amount of answers* with *`z` amount of edits*. **Whilst it's a good idea, I don't think it's needed.**

Answer (score 5):

On second thought, I don't think such badge is required.

HNQ usually gives the author several badges anyway, not to mention lots of reputation. That's more than enough incentive and positive encouragement.

HNQ notification for the asker might be good idea, but using a badge for this is kind of abusing the badge system, that's not the purpose of badges.

All in all, it's not a *bad* idea, just not something that will really add anything, in my opinion.

Comment: I wouldn't mind knowing if/when one of my posts hits the HNQ. That's the most compelling aspect of this feature request, imho.

Comment: @Hamlet true,  but no need in a badge for that. :)