# Request: Keep statistics on a question's HNQ appearance

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, hot-questions

Duplicate, maybe. ([How to see if a question was a "hot network question"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271213/267654))

---

While the HNQ list creates a lot of cross-site traffic (which is wanted), it also causes issues on those sites sometimes, in particular on sites like [PuzzlingSE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) where the 'hotness' of some questions strongly distorts the "voting = quality" paradigm.

However, I'm not about *fixing HNQ* here. Instead, I'm wondering if there is a good method to find out (via query or otherwise) if a question has in the past ever been placed on the HNQ list. ( See also: [What stats should I track in an HNQ list monitor?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295727/267654) )

And if not, I would like to propose this as a general feature request.
The information whether or not a question has been on HNQ is a valueable meta-info which ideally should be captured in the database.

It would allow

- *easy flagging* of such questons in some site design (i.e. an addtional icon)
- *easy filtering* for/against such questions in the search query
- *notification* and *user statistics* ( see: [Should we be notified if we make it onto HNQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294907/should-we-be-notified-if-we-make-it-onto-hnq) )
- *interesting analysis* of the impact of HNQ in various contexts

Comment: I see that this is tagged data-explorer.  Exposing it in SEDE depends on SE exposing it via the database schema; right now there's no hotness data for SEDE to report.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, that's the idea/request. I think it would be exactly what's needed.

Comment: If you want a temporary solution, there are some userscripts that directly tell you if a question is on the hot network, like SOX.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if a question has ever been a "hot network question"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271213/how-to-determine-if-a-question-has-ever-been-a-hot-network-question) - it's available via both the API and SEDE.