# How to track Hot Network Questions on small Beta site

Tags: support, notifications, hot-questions

For better or for worse, a small Beta site sometimes hits the Hot Network Questions list.  Is there a way to set up a trigger such that when this occurs, something happens?  For instance, I get an email or a ping or something?

Comment: related: [Should we be notified if we make it onto HNQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/294907/165773)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such thing built into the network itself. You can probably use the RSS feed for Hot Questions: https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions and have your RSS client filter for the site(s) you're interested in.