# Closed question on Hot Network Questions list

Tags: bug, closed-questions, hot-questions

The question [The list of every type of sound all instruments can make?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/102167/19800) on Music: Practice & Theory Stack Exchange was still on the Hot Network Questions list, despite being closed half an hour ago:

[image]

[image]

The list is supposed to refresh [every three minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287827/295232), so there seems to be some kind of bug here. It *is* gone now but I can't tell whether that is because of the closure or the lack of upvotes (the question has a score of +1 and one answer has +6, that isn't particularly hot).

Comment: I suspect caching.

Comment: @JohnDvorak question refers the statement that list is expected to refresh every three minutes. Seeing one that was became inappropriate 10x longer than that definitely feels like a bug

Comment: @gnat the statement about the HNQ list has surely been cached for longer than three minutes. Is it still accurate?

Comment: @JohnDvorak if that old statement contains stall outdated info, it needs to be refreshed so there is a bug anyway

Comment: There is some deadlock issue in the database, I suspect it's causing all kinds of weird bugs - but let's wait for a dev to confirm and fix. :)

Comment: I just closed a question that was on the Hot Network Questions list and it was indeed removed from the list within several minutes. So that does seem to be the target behavior, and it apparently at least sometimes works.