# Can we get a Hot Network Questions newsletter?

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, newsletter

I love SE's newsletters, and I love going through the hot network questions. There's always something interesting, if not fascinating being asked and answered.

Basically, there are newsletters for everything, except the hot network questions. I bet a lot of people who use SE's various communities are interested in discovering new things, increasing general knowledge and generally observing what's going on.

A Hot Network Questions newsletter would be a perfect solution to satisfying that need. Let's go beyond the ancient RSS feed and make this an inbox darling.

I know there are [solutions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232224/how-can-i-get-a-hot-network-questions-week-digest) but an official service just seems lacking.

Comment: There are the site-specific newsletters which I would probably like more, since the topic is likely to interest me. The biggest issue that I see getting into the way of this is that we have a large list of them, and that they are dynamic (hot points change by the hour). It would be interest to see how this would work :)

Comment: the answer is likely no, for the same reasons as SE team doesn't want to log HNQ history: ["feed speculation and paranoia..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250550/165773) Just think of it, this week newsletter advertizes a bunch of questions and several weeks later, these are [deleted by moderators](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7525/recent-trouble-with-popularity#comment22739_7536). Not good, ain't it