# What makes a question 'hot'?

Tags: discussion, voting, hot-questions

'Hot' StackExchange questions can be seen [here](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), but what exactly is special about them that makes them 'hot'?
Many of these 'hot' questions range from 2-20 upvotes, and range from a minute to a week-or-so old.

They also have low activity.

What's so special about these questions that makes them 'hot'?

Comment: It's only matter of a formula involving amount of upvotes, amount of answers and when it was posted.

Comment: Formula is available here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/

Comment: Also see [How do the "arbitrary hotness points" work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60756), which is arguably the better dupe.

Comment: @MartijnPieters wrong dupe, the one you linked to is talking about the tab in each site, not the network hot questions. The formula is not the same.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yeah, hence the 'arguably better dupe' remark. Feel free to re-open and dupe-hammer close it again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh my, I pasted the wrong URL, lol! Guess we'll leave it be, OP got his answer anyway.

Comment: Looks correct to me though!