# Confusingly displayed arbitrary hotness points

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions, information-display

Over at [the Hot Network Questions page](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot), when you hover over the posts, you get a glimpse at the [arbitrarily awarded hotness points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page) for that specific question.

Here's what I saw:

<kbd>[image: [http://i.imgur.com/ebXUdWI.png]]</kbd>

Whereas the picture above and below it have hotness scores around 8k.
I can only assume a 0 was inappropriately omitted there.

**edit:**
I just realized that the "." is used as a decimal point in most of the English-speaking world. So this is not a bug as much as something that can be mildly confusing to someone who is used to "." being used as a separator between large numbers. (especially since the hotness points are usually precise to exactly 3 digits after the decimal point). Note that I did immediately realize what was meant by this number.

I would argue this number should either be multiplied by 1000 and displayed as a whole number, or the precision should be fixed (to 3 digits after the decimal point for instance)

Answer (score 6):

Personally I wouldn't have thought of it being a number above 1k, as there are multiple numbers having two decimals only.

However I agree that the actual format could lead to confusion for someone not familiar with dots as decimal separator.

IMHO we could just round it (up or down, doesn't really matter), or stop displaying it at all, as it gives no really useful information to people not knowing about what the "hotness" is after all.

At least **I** do not understand what it is used for ;)

Comment: There are indeed multiple numbers with only two decimals, but that should only be about 10%. Since it's only shown on hover and you can get unlucky and only see hotness scores with 3 decimals 20 times in a row or so, (mild) confusion is bound to occur. I personally do like the hotness score, since it gives you and idea of where your question could end up on the list and how long it is likely to stay there, if you're interested in that sort of thing. But that's a discussion for another thread.

Comment: "since it gives you and idea of where your question could end up on the list and how long it is likely to stay there" errr personally it doesn't (and probably for most people), as I don't even know how it is calculated, nor what the maximum/minimum are, but glad it does make sense for you!

Comment: [this answer in linked question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/165773) explains in details how it is calculated