# Bring current site "Hot Question" up in "Hot Network Questions"

Tags: feature-request, sorting, hot-questions

I was thinking in the questions presented in the Hot Network Questions and notice that the order they are presented have no relation to the current site you are in because, I think, they are sorted using the ["hotness calculation"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page). Sometimes you get no questions from the site you are in and sometimes they are presented in different order.

Obviously this is designed to attract users to other networks that might be interesting for them and to draw attention to questions in your same network that are getting a lot of attention without any preference but this makes me think that if they were grouped and placed top, maybe using a separator, they would definitely be more useful without losing its purpose because not all the other sites might be interesting topics to the SO users and is impossible to figure out all the topic you might be interested in by just  random.

This way you get when scrolling from top to bottom:

- Blog
- Featured on Meta
- Hot Meta Post
- Linked questions
- Related questions
- Hot questions from the same network
- All the other hot questions

Please note that I'm not trying to create another block of content or alter the algorithm used to get which question should appear, just a last sort on the results to make this block more useful.

This is a pic of how they are showing right now

[image: current question sort]

And this is how I think they should be. Using a separator is open for debate.

[image: intended sort]

The main reason for this is that we already know the probability of this questions are of interest is higher compared with the rest of the questions.

Comment: The sort is currently totally random, changing with each reload. Or more accurate to say, X random hot questions are taken from the list of 100 hot questions, and shuffled, where X is up to 25. (I think.)

Comment: Yes I think so too. If you take the remaining 25 and move the matching network questions up after that, it will make them stand out without changing the way Hot Questions works