# Hot Questions should be determined by the number of answerers, not answers

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

I'd like to propose a small change in the [formula to determine hot questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/295232):

```
(MIN(AnswerCount, 10) * QScore) / 5 + AnswerScore
-------------------------------------------------
         MAX(QAgeInHours + 1, 6) ^ 1.4
```

The `AnswerCount` should count the number of distinct answer*er*s, instead of the number of answers. This would prevent questions like [this one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/94468/38979) from appearing in the Hot Network Questions sidebar. I don't have anything against this specific question, but five answers by five different users are a way better indication of a question's hotness than five answers by a single user.

[image]

Comment: I think this makes sense although I normally can't be bothered why, how or when questions become hot but I'm a minority ...

Comment: In general, the Hot Network Questions scoring and system needs reworking. I agree with this change, but if we're going to talk about changing the scoring I suggest a more in depth look at the scoring and ideas  to improve it. For example, the users of the SE should have some way to influence questions that are "hot" as for some sites it's common to see questions that don't represent the community pop up as Hot Questions.