# Can a Hot Network Question have no answers?

Tags: support, hot-questions

Typically, the more answers a post has, the more likely it is to become a Hot Network Question.

**Is it possible for a post with 0 answers to become a Hot Network Question?**

Comment: I think hot n/w questions are decided based on votes, visits and all activities

Comment: @SagarV no, it is based on scores of both question and answers, as well as question age. See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## No.

From [How do the “arbitrary hotness points” work on the new Stack Exchange home page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/209901):

> - Questions with no answers are excluded

As Shadow correctly points in comments, this comes immediately from the formula:

```
(MIN(AnswerCount, 10) * QScore) / 5 + AnswerScore
-------------------------------------------------
         MAX(QAgeInHours + 1, 6) ^ 1.4
```

If `AnswerCount = 0`, then obviously `AnswerScore = 0`, so the hotness of a particular question without answers would be 0:

```
  (MIN(0, 10) * QScore) / 5 + 0       0/5 + 0
--------------------------------- = ------------ = 0
  MAX(QAgeInHours + 1, 6) ^ 1.4       whatever
```

Comment: Though this is pointless, as 0 answers will always result in 0 in the formula to calculate hotness score. ((MIN(AnswerCount, 10) * QScore) / 5 + AnswerScore))

Comment: @ShadowWizard Is that the top AnswerScore or combined AnswerScore for each answer?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro [sum of all answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page/61343#comment636073_61343)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro see update with the formula.

Comment: I wonder if it would drop off the list if answers were deleted for some reason...

Comment: @Rory of course, deleted answers don't count. But since the list is cached for long time (think up to one hour), it will take a while until the question drops off the list.