# Mark questions with accepted answer in the Hot Network Questions list

Tags: feature-request, design, hot-questions

I am hereby proposing a new feature for the hot network questions (HNQ): The questions shall be bordered green if answered (answer marked as accepted) and gray if not (like in the question lists).

This would be good in many situations: At example for Puzzle.SE. I would like to see whether a puzzle has been solved yet or is still uncracked.

Or maybe I have a problem that is featured in the HNQ-list and you happily click on the link only to see that it is not answered.

I have created an example mockup showing what I want to have:

> [image: my mockup]

As you can see there wouldn't be much code change neccessary. Also the database tables already store the information whether a question is answered (answer marked as accepted) or not so this wouldn't be a big API-change.

Comment: [Questions without answers are excluded from Hot Network Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/how-do-the-arbitrary-hotness-points-work-on-the-new-stack-exchange-home-page).

Comment: @Ano edited to clarify that I mean no accepted answers