# What mechanisms encourage answering long-unanswered, upvoted questions?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, participation

This is not a complaint or suggestion, it's an informative question.

What automated mechanisms does Stack Exchange have in place to encourage the community to answer questions which have a positive score, but no positive-score answers, and no recent activity?

Comment: Just a joke: The tumbleweed badge, to encourage bumping?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Isn't that only for no-vote questions? ... in which case, it's a ha-ha-only-serious kind of a joke.

Comment: No, just a joke ... Wait, there's the necromancer badge as well :-P.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That's ex-post-facto; that doesn't bring up questions to people's attention.

Comment: There's probably no _"automated"_ mechanism that encourages to do that. All of them involve some user interaction it seems. Should I post that as an answer, or should we wait some month (years)?

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention the _unanswered questions_  tab, but that also involves a user being willing to have a look at it.

Comment: The community user bumps such questions periodically to give them facetime on the front oage

Comment: @DoubleAA No, Community doesn't bump questions with no answers. The point of Community bumps isn't to get attention for questions, it's to get attention for unreviewed answers.

Answer (score 3):

Every SE site has an ["unanswered questions" tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered), where such questions should appear, and ordered by votes these should appear prominently.
Appearing there is automated, but still needs an OP being interested about that view, and selecting it.

Also these might appear in the "hot network questions" sidebar, regarding to their upvotes.

Can you tell more distinct what you're seem to be missing? Personal notifications about a particular tag or site?
There's also a newsletter you can subscribe IIRC.

Comment: When I go to the home page, I see "interesting", "featured", "hot", week" and "month". None of these are for unanswered questions solely (plus it's not easy to figure out what they mean, but that's a different issue).

Comment: The HNQ sidebar [only shows newish questions with answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/323179).

Comment: @einpoklum You need to go to the Questions tab: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @PolyGeo: Why-ever would I do that? The homepage shows me questions, lots of questions, in many tabs. What reason would I have to click on "questions" from the homepage?

Comment: @einpoklum Not sure why you would, but I do it to find highly upvoted yet unanswered questions.  It's easy to do and very effective.

Comment: @einpoklum for one, iirc the main homepage doesn't do pagination. It shows n questions and that's it. The questions page has pagination, so you can see more than just the last n questions.