# Should upvotes on new answers to old/unanswered/upvoted questions be weighted differently?

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions

**Note:** This question has marked as a possible duplicate of: [How about a difficulty rating for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3811/1377755)

**However:** This question is not about a *'difficulty rating'* for questions based on their perceived or actual *'difficulty'* in any way shape or form. This is about questions that have been **unanswered** for a long time, which may or may not correlate with difficulty and can also be the case for other reasons. The answers at the other question respond to the idea of users rating the *'difficulty'* of (their own) questions and thus are not relevant here.

---

Some questions are answered right away. Whether or not they are duplicates or closed, even if they are well-researched and on-topic, they receive answers within their first day, and most of the time, problem solved.

On the other hand, there are the more neglected questions which remain unanswered for weeks, months, even years after being posted. Sometimes they are about an obscure or localized edge-case or about an obscure technology that comparatively few people use. But they still deserve to be answered.

While there are mechanisms to [find](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308422/1377755) such questions, as far as I can tell, aside from a few badges (Revival, Necromancer) there is no special reward for answering such questions as opposed to the ones that have received adequate attention. I believe there should be, because answers to nuanced/uncommon questions are inherently scarcer, and thus should be rewarded more.

One solution the system has is bounties. Users can offer a bounty on a question to give a bonus of reputation to an answer. However, a bounty is a luck of the draw. I have seen bounties, even of the +500 kind, nearing their expiry with no new answers, or no answers at all. And of course you need reputation to offer a bounty.

However, what would be the consequences of a more universal mechanism to encourage finding and answering old unanswered questions?

I thought that maybe if a question remains unanswered for a certain period of time (6 months or 1 year), any new answer would have its upvotes give the answer author more than the current +10 reputation.

Would a feature to weight the reputation gains on answers **based on how long the question existed before the first answer was added** help give the neglected questions a better chance at being answered, or have any negative unforeseen consequences?

Comment: FYI, I also proposed having upvotes to answers to somewhat older questions receiving a higher reputation than +10 in this [answer](/a/387430) (which I deleted due to it being received poorly) to [The Stack Exchange reputation system: What's working? What's not?](/q/387356). In particular, my initial suggestion was for +12 for answers posted more than than 7 days after a question was asked. However, my main reasoning was regarding a sense of fairness due to newer, similar quality answers usually getting considerably more upvotes. OTOH, I like your reasons more than mine, and also waiting ...

Comment: (cont.) longer (e.g., your suggestion of 6 months or 1 year) is better than my idea of just 7 days. As for the particular details, such as how much of an increase of reputation per upvote would be appropriate, that's hard to say since if it's too little, there won't be much incentive for people to take the extra time and effort to answer. OTOH, if it's too much, there may be concerns that it unfairly rewards a new answer to older questions, especially if those questions were actually relatively easy to answer but, for whatever reason, just didn't receive any answers earlier.

Comment: What would this be solving exactly? many low quality answers get posted to old, long-answered questions every week, implementing a system that provides additional rep to these answers doesn't seem to be something that would really... promote anything useful. the problem we have with answers to older questions is they don't receive enough votes in general, not that the users who post useful ones aren't rewarded adequately.

Comment: @user16217248 long-unanswered questions are more often than not in need of deletion than an answer. It's not that they're hard, it's that they're poorly researched/written.

Comment: @KevinB Well, if the question is upvoted, it's more likely to be the in need of an answer kind rather than the in need of deletion kind.

Comment: @user16217248 not necessarily. people vote weirdly sometimes.

Comment: The question remains, though, what does giving users 2 more rep for answering some old abandoned question do to improve the network? If it were a question people were seeking an answer to.. surely it wouldn't have been abandoned.

Comment: limiting it to, say, +5, on SO, gives us 39k questions with 0 answers, which sounds like a large number... but... that's only 13-ish days worth of questions, among 14 years of questions. it's a very small number and there's a farily good chance *most* of these questions are answered in the comments, just noone's bothered to move the comment answer to an answer. does that deserve more rep? is it more important to get answers to these questions from 3, 5, 8, 10 years ago as opposed to more recent questions? We already aren't even close to keeping up with daily new questions.

Comment: @KevinB It is hard to get statistics on comment-answered questions but most of the ones I click on don't have a definitive answer in the comments. Besides, if one moved a comment to an answer, they should have made it community wiki unless they are the owner of the comment. Lowering the bar to +2 instead of +5 gives more than 10x as many questions as +5.

Comment: That only strengthens my argument. There are far more pressing matters to deal with, such as new incoming questions, than these older questions that the authors have abandoned. I doubt people are all that interested in finally getting an answer about how to solve that error in ios11.

Comment: @KevinB Not all unanswered questions that are old have been 'abandoned' by their authors. Besides, future readers might want answers, even if the author left or lost their password or deleted their account. Why do you think new incoming questions are more 'pressing'/important than old questions that received no answers? Not all 'old' questions are 'outdated' questions about technology no one uses anymore.

Comment: Because old questions that received no answers aren't guarenteed to have at least 1 person who actually needs the answer still.

Comment: @user16217248 I'm sorry if the canned comment that was automatically added by the system when I voted to close as duplicate confused you about how voting to close as duplicate works. I will delete the comment but my vote stays. Before voting to close as duplicate, I posted an "answer," but I got some comments saying it doesn't "answer" the question.  I might return later to explain my vote to close as duplicate and / or undeleted my "answer". In the meantime, I let you know that the premise of this question needs more work.

Comment: @Rubén Why do you think this is a duplicate? I think it's not.

Comment: I'm not 100% on board with the duplicate closure, but I can't come to disagree enough to vote to reopen. I've decided to [move the bulk of my answer to the dup-target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394790/997587).

Comment: I have *voted to close as a duplicate* of [How about a difficulty rating for questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/) because that post looks like a canonical question about [tag:question-difficulty]. The OP's edit argued based on making a literal comparison instead of discussing the **underlying canonical discussion**. The OP has not considered that the target question is linked to many questions. TL;DR IMHO, for this question to be reopened, it should altogether **remove the question difficulty** as an attribute to consider or should better support the claims on this post

Comment: @Rubén I still don't see how that canonical discussion is relevant here, or warranting of duplicate closure. Again, it's only tangentially related at best. But I have edited the question again nevertheless. I fail to see how question difficulty was ever an attribute to consider, as this hypothetical change takes only into account a questions age without answers.

Comment: I read the answers in the dup-target and none of them address the actual FR here due to the difference in mechanics for assigning difficulty rating. the top three answers are about problems the other FR's assignment mechanism. [4th top answer](/a/69392) is just agreement with the motivation, [5th answer](/a/3881) is an alternate assignment mechanism suggestion. so are the 6th and 7th. 8th and inspectorG4dget's answer is more design criticism of the specific mechanic. Pollyanna's answer seems to disagree on the motivation. djechlin's answer is part of the motivation for this FR. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR I think the reward is there implicitly if the question has a high score. If you answer and people find your answer helpful, I believe that the upvotes will come in some degree of proportion to question score (as long as people still want the answer and nothing happened to significantly outmode it).

Somewhat tangentially, I think it would be nice if the site UI put some emphasis on the follow button for people who try to upvote unanswered questions. Also, better education about how to use search to find such questions for people who want to answer them.

Before reading what follows, note that it was originally written when the question had some framing around question difficulty, though that part of its framing has since been removed.

---

What I have personally come to think/accept is that- if anything- the closest thing that reputation represents is the usefulness of one's content over time. This has allowed me to come to terms with the fact that some people have tons of rep for answering a very common and "easy" question (because it is *useful* to many people), and with the fact that some of the answers which I am the most proud of writing to answer some obscure question, displaying some higher degree of technical prowess / knowledge (Ex. about a puzzling edge-case) will never earn as much rep as my answers to a questions about highly visible software bugs.

As an answerer, do I wish that I would be rewarded more for answering a question which I think is more "difficult"? Yes.

Do I think that there is some *systematic, scalable, non-controversial, objective, and accurate* way to judge the "difficulty" of a question? No.

Do I think that striving for that matters if "difficulty" is to be baked into the reputation system and apply to everyone? (hesitantly) ... Yes.

In a way, that's not very fair of me to say. Because I don't think "helpfulness" / "usefulness" meets the above criterion either. And yet we have a mechanism for judging that and rewarding that- in fact- it is *the primary* mechanism on Stack Exchange for rewarding anything: the upvote button. I suppose you could say it's systematic and scalable, but just as with "difficulty", "usefulness" is in the eye of the beholder. **But**, do I think Stack Exchange would be significantly better as a whole if there was a "reward the author of this answer because I think the question was difficult" button? No. Not when there's already a button that generally means "this is useful to me".

If you were to ask me what quality I think should be prioritized in choosing questions to answer- questions that are "difficult / of technical interest to experts" versus questions that more people want the answer to, I would choose the latter for effort-reward purposes. Also note /help/dont-ask's emphasis on practicality (which I'm aware is something also difficult to evaluate, and that not all network sites may have the same emphasis on, but which I find worth mentioning nonetheless).

I should probably say now that I don't think reputation is a good measure of how much someone can be trusted with higher site privileges, so I haven't factored that consideration into the above thoughts. I'm only thinking of reputation as an incentive mechanism. Also, I'm ignoring the weirder sites like Puzzling, Code Golf, etc.

---

Time is a weak proxy for "difficulty". As you've said, some questions go unanswered just because it's a low-traffic tag / uncommon technology. If you want to handle that, then you need to scale by tag traffic- but how? and how do you handle the change in a tag's popularity over time? This seems to just bring up more questions and complexities.

There are also other nuances I see unhandled (but that are addressable by adding complexity). Ex. time which a question spends closed (I don't think that should contribute to additional answering reward).

> a feature to weight the reputation gains on answers based on how long the question existed before the first answer was added

And what if I answer a "really hard" question right when it's asked because I happen to be there at the right place and right time to help out? Either the heuristic fails to achieve its purpose, or it motivates counterproductive and perverse mind-games where experts choose to wait to answer something to scale the rep gain.

I think the idea of looking at question score is valuable. But the way I see it, the problem is then already solved. As I've said, I'd rather prioritize (and therefore incentivize) usefulness than "difficulty". If a question has many upvotes, guess what? many people have indicated that it is useful to them. *If/when* an answer comes, and if that answer is useful to the kind of person who found the question useful, that answer will probably receive a proportionally large number of upvotes over time.

Also, if you're waiting on an answer to a question you're interested in, every page for an unanswered question has the following text:

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Twitter, or Facebook.

---

I say this all as someone who has spent a *significant* amount of time being the one *searching* for and answering questions that have high scores and few or no answers or no accepted answer. If readers find the question and the answer useful, I can tell you that the upvotes come. It will feel like they come painfully slowly or that they're not coming at all, but they come.

And it does not go unnoticed. I've had a random redditor tell me that when they were trying to learn about the subject of one of my tags, they noticed that I was often the only answerer in the Q&A they looked at, and they thanked me for being helpful and informative.

This is going on a bit of a tangent now, but since we're on the topic of rewarding people who write answers to such questions- questions which have a notable handful of upvotes, but nothing like the most common/popular questions, I have wondered before: To what degree are answers to questions that went unanswered for a long time and which people find useful not getting upvotes because readers don't have voting privileges? It's a weird question to ask, but I felt like mentioning it, since this was the one question I had in my mind pushing me toward interest in [the 1-rep voting experiment](/q/393127/997587)- something I mostly was very reserved about / leaning against- at least for SO.

Comment: And even "usefulness" can be taken with a grain of salt: it's sometimes more akin to 'understandability', in the sense that an answer can be easily verified, by anyone (with no prior knowledge), as being (or seeming) true. (As a specific example I'm thinking of the game identification questions on Arqade, which garner both parties lots of rep, but are only really useful to the OP and regularly don't show signs of effort from the OP. These Q&As also exemplify FGITW).

Comment: We have a "reward the author of this answer because I think the question was difficult" button. If you feel that someone wrote a great answer to a hard question you can give them a bounty.