# How can I check how hot a question is?

Tags: support, questions, hot-questions

When a question gets to [the "Hot Network Questions" tab](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) you can hover it to see how many hotness points it has.

[image: "This question has been arbitrarily awarded x hotness points" tooltip]

<sup>(Note this doesn't occur for the HNQ list in the bottom right of most pages, it's just for the central HNQ page.)</sup>

Is there any way to get that information for any other questions that aren't there?

Comment: Looks like [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284933/152859) is what you want.

Comment: That script made by an user that tries to calculate the percentage (not points) of questions doesn't look very accurate/reliable. I wish there was a better way (preferably official / featured by the network site itself) but I guess I'm out of luck and that question isn't specific to this so I can't ask for that there.

Comment: It's not possible since each site got its own "weight" which is not public.

Comment: @ShadowtheWelcomingWizard Isn't it possible to reverse engineer the exact formula from the data exposed from knowing how many points the hot questions have?

Comment: Maybe, you're welcome to try, then SEDE query will also be possible. :-)