# Does the reputation of the participants in the question affect the "hotness?"

Tags: support, reputation, hot-questions

This is my second question on hot network questions. I was shocked to find this question that I asked on the list: [If a collection of closed sets of arbitrary cardinality in a metric space has empty intersection, does some countable subcollection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3106782/187867)

The amount of activity on the question is quite small, however I have 38K rep and the two users who answered the question have over 100K rep. This made me wonder if maybe the reputation had something to do with it.

I combed through the hot network questions at the time and found that many did have quite high reputation users participating, but there was at least one where no one was over 1K. However, that question had 160+ upvotes, whereas mine has 3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope.

That question and its answers have a pretty decent score in a very short period of time.

At the time you asked this question, they had already scored

- Q: 3 (+4/-1)
- A1: 5
- A2: 4

Before it was an hour old, it had a score of two and an accepted answer with a score of three.

This actually makes for a pretty good hotness score. The second answer arrived about an hour and a half after the question was asked so that by the time the question was two hours old it had the following score:

- Q: 3 (all up)
- A1: 4
- A2: 2

The HNQ pretty much only cares about

- the score of the question
- the score its answers
- the quantity of answers (up to 10)
- how recently the question was posted

The exact formula, as reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/284336) is:

> ```
> (MIN(AnswerCount, 10) * QScore) / 5 + AnswerScore  
> -------------------------------------------------  
>         MAX(QAgeInHours + 1, 6) ^ 1.4
> ```

Feel free to do the math, if you like but, as you can see from the linked post, reputation of the user has no direct effect. I say "direct" because it's not uncommon to see high rep users earn more upvotes because they look more trustworthy.