# Should I edit the squares in this title? Is it just me who's seeing them?

Tags: support, special-characters

I show some screen shots below. The title to the question [What substance has the lowest Kₛₚ value?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/27842/16035) shows a "K" and then two squares to me, but nobody has edited it.

The body says:

> What substance has the lowest $K_\mathrm{sp}$ and what is its value? The lowest I could find is $2.6\cdot 10^{-124}$ for cobalt(III) sulfide $\ce{Co2S3}$.

and in Chemistry SE that is rendered properly (see screen shot below).

So the squares represent a subscripted "sp", I'm guessing for the word "specific".

I thought "Oh I'll fix this" and found a subscript s on `compart.com` but it also displays as a big red square on my screen!

Is this just me and everyone else sees "sp" or is there something else going on?

Just fyi I have MacOS 10.11 (old, yes I know) and Chrome browser

> [image: screen shot of question "What substance has the lowest Kₛₚ value?]
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKm9N.png

From https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+209B

> [image: screen shot of https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+209B]

Comment: Looks like your font lacks support for Unicode characters. [My screenshot (Chromium@Windows 10 2004)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD6GB.png).

Comment: @andselisk see [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351276/should-i-edit-the-squares-in-this-title-is-it-just-me-whos-seeing-them/351277#comment1176471_351277)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use Apple products and I have very limited understanding how their font subsystem works these days. I've just checked the post on a Linux machine (Arch with KDE) and Kₛₚ was rendered all right too. Note, however, that this doesn't seem to be an SE-specific issue since your browser also fails to render Unicode characters on compart.com.

Comment: @andselisk fyi I've just asked in Apple SE: [Why can't I see subscript "s" (Unicode Character “ₛ” (U+209B)) even though I can see lots of other unicode characters?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/396864/143729)

Comment: Thank you for raising this issue. I'll keep in mind to limit usage of non-ASCII symbols in my posts and edits for better compatibility, just like [orthocresol nicely did in his edit to this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/27842/3).

Comment: I also see various types of boxes instead of the subscripts using iOS (happens both in browser and in app).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I edit the squares in this title?

No.

> Is it just me who's seeing them?

No, but many people <s>do</s> did see them until the Chemistry SE moderator deleted them from the title.

It's just that several macOS installations don't show that particular unicode character. [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/396865/143729) in Apple SE explains further, and comments there explain that while some unicodes like "subscript i" are included in your configuration, others like "subscript s" are not.

> The display of any unicode character requires that your machine has a font installed which contains the glyph for it.  Apple doesn't provide fonts for all 130000 unicode characters.  For U+209b you need to download one.  A possible [list](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/209b/fontsupport.htm) is here.

Apparently Apple left out subscript s so that they could include a "crying emoji" so that you can express your confusion about how unicode works.

Answer (score 5):

For me, at least, using either Edge 84.0.522.40 or Chrome 84.0.4147.89 on Windows 10, the question's title shows correctly (note the image below comes from when using Edge):

> [image: Inorganic chemistry question on Chemistry SE]

Comment: The question has just been edited and Ksp removed from the title, but when I looked at the edit history with my new laptop with new MacOS 10.15 and Safari browser I still see the squares, so I don't think it was due to my old laptop's OS being old at least.

Comment: @uhoh I'm not a member of Chemistry SE, so I couldn't edit the question text to see what it uses for the title. However, I suspect the issue is likely due to what [andselisk](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/362412/andselisk)'s question [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351276/should-i-edit-the-squares-in-this-title-is-it-just-me-whos-seeing-them/351277#comment1176470_351276) states, i.e., you are missing some Unicode characters, although that is surprising to have it happen in a new laptop computer, unless it's perhaps related to Mac vs. Windows.

Comment: But I don't see how it's just "me" that's missing it, I've tried on two different laptops with very different versions of MacOS and different browsers. I'll ask a separate question in Apple SE about this.

Comment: @JohnOmielan On Chemistry.SE, [it was decided *not* to use MJ in titles](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/is-mathjax-in-titles-a-problem-and-why). Use of Unicode was intentional.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I've just asked in Apple SE: [Why can't I see subscript "s" (Unicode Character “ₛ” (U+209B)) even though I can see lots of other unicode characters?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/396864/143729)

Comment: @uhoh Note that MathJax in the title automatically disqualifies a question from the HNQ.

Comment: @PM2Ring wow that's an interesting factoid; *thanks!*

Comment: @uhoh You can read about the details of the HNQ selection algorithm here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343/334566 Note that editing MathJax into a title purely to block it or remove it from the HNQ is generally frowned upon. It's now possible to use a custom mod flag to suggest HNQ removal, but you need to make a strong case. (I know the Physics.SE mods prefer poor HNQ questions be removed by the organic process of being close voted, rather than by mod intervention).

Comment: @PM2Ring okay, [I like asking HNQs](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1030066/users-whose-posts-got-most-times-hnq-ed-network-wide) so I'll avoid MathJax in titles even on the sites where it's encouraged.