# Hottest answers of all time on a specifc tag not right

Tags: bug, tags, answers, hot-answers

When I looked at the [hottest answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/discussion/hot?filter=all) for the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag, I realized that some answers were missing from the list, like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper/333968#333968) one.

[image]

An even bigger example is the [python](/questions/tagged/python) tag on Stack Overflow, it shows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/hot?filter=all) that the highest upvoted answer is with 6539 votes, but actually, it should be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do/231855#231855) answer with 15.3k+ upvotes.

Comment: There's a formula to calculate the hotness of a question, which can be seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61343). The hottest questions aren't (always) the questions with the most votes!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the criteria for questions to be selected for Hot Network Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/what-are-the-criteria-for-questions-to-be-selected-for-hot-network-questions)

Comment: @Luuklag It's not a dupe, that is for HNQ, i am asking for the hottest answers page on specific tags

Comment: @U11-Forward It explains what hotness is, which is not the amount of votes as you reason. So it explains perfectly.