# What user actions cause a proposal to be listed on the 'hot' tab of Area 51?

Tags: discussion, area-51, users, hot-questions

Today I noticed on Area 51 that some actions cause a proposal to jump to the top of the 'hot' tab. Which is, of course, an important place to be.  And on the other hand, some user actions don't trigger the same response.

So I'm just curious what actions cause a proposal to jump to the top of the 'hot' tab?

Comment: I suspect it involves putting "Justin Bieber" in the title, but do not wish to test this theory.

Comment: lol, There are a couple similar Area 51 proposals I think will take off, but I don't want to be responsible for the sad questions that will ensue from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Area 51 was implemented, it was based on the Stack Exchange code base. As such:

- "SE questions" became "Area 51 proposals"
- "SE Answers" became "Area 51 example questions"
- "SE voting" became "Area 51 voting"

Given that correlation, I'm reasonably certain that the "hotness" of a proposal is based roughly on the same criteria as a "hot" question in Stack Exchange. The algorithm is described here:

[How are “Hot” Questions Selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected)

*The Area 51 devs can reply, if I am mistaken.*