# Inconsistent tab labels

Tags: support, questions, tabs

The top page of Stack Overflow has the tabs **Interesting** and **Hot**, which I understand as '*the reverse order of time questioned,*' and  '*the reverse order of time of some activity on it*', but when I filter the questions with a tag, the tab labels change to **Newest** and **Active**, which I understand to mean the same thing. Is my understanding correct? If so, why are the labels different? If there is no particular reason, I would prefer them to be unified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Hot**: [How are questions in the 'hot' tab on a site selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected)
- **Interesting**: [Stack Overflow Homepage Changes](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/)

These are indeed different from **Newest** and **Active**.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that. So there is no way to see all the questions in the reverse time order without filtering with some tag?

Comment: Click on the Questions button.

Comment: @sawa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest