# How do the "Interesting" and "Hot" tabs work?

Tags: support

I see two tabs, "Interesting" and "Hot" on [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com). How do they work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you hover over the tab names in the user interface, a tooltip will appear to describe them to you:

Interesting:

> Questions that may be of interest to you based on your history and tag
>   preferences

Hot:

> Questions with the most views, answers and votes over the last few
>   days

[This related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected) discusses the selection of "Hot" questions in more detail.

[image]