# Stackoverflow should send question to experts

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ask a question and notify users on specific users list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71727/ask-a-question-and-notify-users-on-specific-users-list)
>   [How could I notify Stack Overflow's expert users about my new question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103086/how-could-i-notify-stack-overflows-expert-users-about-my-new-question)

I should be posible to have a special inbox for experts (>1K reputation) where stackoverflow sends them questions they could solve.

E.g: J. J. Jameson knows a lot of Haskell in web apps. He has a lots of accepted answers in that theme. So, the new questions (tagged Haskell and Web) are sended to J.J. Jameson request inbox to prevent J.J. spent time watching all the questions.

Comment: Can we send all of the mediocre ones your way, then?

Comment: J.J. Jameson can come to the SO and subscribe to Haskell tag to get related questions, if he want that. No reason to spam somebody.

Comment: See: [What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do), [How do the “Interesting” and “Hot” tabs work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118796/how-do-the-interesting-and-hot-tabs-work) and above all: [filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters).

Comment: Yep, let's set this up for Jon Skeet as well, I don't think he's anywhere near max'ing out his potential on our site.

Comment: What, Jenna Jameson is an expert in Haskell? Who'd have guessed!

Answer (score 8):

And how would we keep this from being **incredibly annoying**?

I mean, who *wouldn't* want to have their question answered by an expert? How do we keep people from spamming [Jon Skeet's inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) with all of their C#/.NET questions? Or [Raymond Chen's inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) with all of their Win32 API questions? Or [John Resig's inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6524/john-resig) with all of their jQuery and JavaScript questions? Or…

No thanks.

Just tag your question appropriately, give it a descriptive and interesting title, and the experts will see and answer it just like everyone else. That's the whole point of a Q&A site like Stack Overflow.

Besides, there are some super smart people that have not yet been pegged as "experts". Would it really be so bad if you got an answer from them, instead?

Comment: How about we forward all meta questions to **your** inbox? ;)

Comment: @Lix Ugh, already happens for moderators on all meta sites but this one!

Comment: Oy... really?  Well... wasn't me... ;)