# How to know the ranking of a certain question in the hot question list?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, hot-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are “Hot” Questions Selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected)

Is there a way to know the ranking (appearance) of a certain question on Stack Overflow in the hot questions list?

Comment: Which one? Your question will appear in a *lot* of lists...

Comment: You mean hot questions list?

Comment: I mean the hot question list indeed.

Comment: I fear there is no such way currently.

Comment: @Shog9  "The How are Hot questions Selected?" Is mainly targeting the algorithm itself. This question is about finding information about the ranking status of a certain question not how such information is found.

Comment: @Future2020: all of the inputs to the algorithm are public - you should be able to calculate the "score" based on that. I don't know why you'd want to, but...