# What’s the difference between top, interesting, hot, faq and featured questions?

Tags: support, questions, user-interface

What makes these questions classified in any of these categories?

Comment: Here's [Hot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/148672) and [Featured](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/148672). Interesting is based on your history and tags you've favorited/ignored

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can hover your mouse over the tabs and it will give you a brief, one sentence summary for each.

[image]

Here's a listing of tabs groupings and their summaries,

- **interesting**: questions that may be of interest to you based on your history and tag preferences
- **featured**: questions with an open bounty
- **hot**: questions with the most views, answers, and votes over the last few days
- **week**: questions with the most views, answers, and votes this week
- **month**: questions with the most views, answers and votes this month
- **newest**: the most recently asked questions
- **faq**: questions with the most links
- **votes**: questions with the most votes
- **active**: questions that have recent activity
- **unanswered**: questions that have no upvoted answers

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the hover info but thanks any way!

Comment: "questions with the most links" is not clear to me.  The most links to the question from other SE questions?  The most external links pointing to the question?

Comment: I'm also curious as to what exactly "questions with the most links" means. Can anyone clarify this?

Comment: @Alex "hot: questions with the most views, answers, and votes over the **last few days**". How may days?

Comment: @Geek I don't think a specific time frame is specified (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Jeff Atwood explains the formula used to determine "hotness" of questions in his answer to: [How are questions in the 'hot' tab on a site selected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4766/335251)