# How to get all the tabs for questions

Tags: support, questions, user-interface

So I was reading this question...

[What’s the difference between top, interesting, hot, faq and featured questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135728/whats-the-difference-between-top-interesting-hot-faq-and-featured-questions)

I noticed I don't have some of those tabs (like hot or interesting).  Do these come from having more rep, or are they a setting from somewhere, or am I missing something?

Comment: Are you on the front page?

Comment: Haha, no I was clicked on question.  Though I guess that spawns another question that perhaps I should make another thread for.  Why are the tabs different from the main page and the questions button?

Comment: It really is all about context.