# How are the top questions of the "week" and "month" calculated?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, hot-questions, top-questions

Jeff Atwood explained a while ago how "hot" questions are selected in this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected).

However, I am wondering how are the "top questions of the week" and "month" calculated? Is it by a slightly modified version of the "hot questions" algorithm, or is it completely different?

Comment: I think it's the same, but without the time factor/penalty.