# "Hot" tab contains not-so-hot questions

Tags: discussion

I have seen the posts about how the questions are selected for the "hot" tab on SO, but I think it's weird that the list often contains questions with < 20 views, no answers, no edits, and < 2 comments. Does anyone else think there should be minimums of > 20 views OR > 2 answers OR > 3 comments to be included in this list?

Comment: @Glorfindel this is about the [tab for Hot questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co4fp.png), which is very different from the HNQ we know, and using totally different formula. The [tag:hot-tab] tag is wrongly synonymized with the [tag:hot-questions] tag, so can't use it either. Until sorted out, better remove the tag.

Comment: I see. I intentionally added the [hot-tab] tag but didn't notice it was synonymized. I'm writing a Meta post to discuss this situation right now.

Comment: @Glorfindel cheers, it has very few questions so wasn't sure it's worth such effort. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's necessary.  There's a time component in calculating hotness.  The [formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/1288) also uses the log of the views, not the raw number of views, so if a question gets to the "hot" tab on views alone, it will drop off quickly if it doesn't get any answers, edits, or votes.