# Let's clean up [hot-questions] and (un)related tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, hot-questions

We currently have the following 'hot' tags on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [hot-questions](/questions/tagged/hot-questions)

  > Hot Network Questions in the right-hand sidebar, the “hot” tab on each site, and on stackexchange.com.
- [hot-tab](/questions/tagged/hot-tab), which is synonymized to [hot-questions](/questions/tagged/hot-questions) yet has a different excerpt:

  > Questions about the Hot tab of the Top Questions page.
- [hot-answers](/questions/tagged/hot-answers), a [little known functionality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/support/hot) for which I just added an excerpt:

  > NOTE: hot answers are different from answers to Hot Network Questions; use the [hot-questions] tag instead. This tag is only for questions about the 'hot answers' feature on tag info pages.

The difference between the excerpts led me to make a wrong edit here: ["Hot" tab contains not-so-hot questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146920/295232) which was fortunately caught by an observant user.

[image]

Since really the only thing that links the 'hot tab' and the 'Hot Network Questions' is the *word* 'hot', and the features are so different in terms of impact, controversy and purpose, I propose to:

- unsynonymize [hot-questions](/questions/tagged/hot-questions) and [hot-tab](/questions/tagged/hot-tab)

  - we have to manually check if questions about the 'hot' tab are correctly tagged, but I expect no more than a dozen issues
- rename [hot-questions](/questions/tagged/hot-questions) to [hot-network-questions](/questions/tagged/hot-network-questions), since that's the name everybody knows them under

I have already removed the [hot-answers](/questions/tagged/hot-answers) tag from a few questions where it didn't apply.

Thoughts?

Comment: No burninate request here, at least not directly... renaming a tag isn't same as burninating it.

Comment: You're right; I originally thought [hot-answers] needed to be burninated but it turns out they *do* exist: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/support/hot

Comment: This tagging layout probably comes from the pre-2014 top bar and site layout, when HNQ wasn't called that and in the sidebar, but called "Hot Questions" and shown in the top bar.

Comment: While we're at it, can we please make [tag:hot-meta-posts] a synonym of [tag:community-bulletin]?