# How are SE-wide Hot Questions selected?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

How are the hot questions in the Stack Exchange dropdown in the upper left corner selected? I saw [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4766/how-are-hot-questions-selected), but it's talking about the per-site hot questions, not the SE-wide ones.