# What sorts of order in hot questions tab?

Tags: discussion, sorting, views, hot-questions

In hot questions tab [Hot Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot), I can't determine which sorts of order was invoke.
By hoverring on *hot* tab , below message was appeared.

> Questions with the most views,answers and votes over the last few days

But in case , that's similar randomly.

- not order by view counts
- not by answer counts
- not by vote points ( up or down or up + down )
- and not by date-time

I thought , "*ah ! first top of question was hottest and followed by others with orderly.*"
As hover message that I described (brief information of tab ) , I assume these are ordered by

***view counts > answer counts > vote counts ....***

Can anyone explain to me ?

Comment: It's ordered by points/score. Let me find the formula... [here it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/152859).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ordered by "hotness points". The formula to calculate those points can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/152859).

If you're too lazy to calculate yourself, you can hover the title of any hot question in [the list](https://stackexchange.com/questions):

> [image]

And until the new top bar with the new MultiCollider rolls out to all the sites, you can see it there too:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for valuable answers...I think orderring by hotness points , that will not familiar for newbie ( as like me ). :D

Comment: @Cataclysm true, that's not trivial indeed. :)