# What does Qupdated mean in the formula for selecting hot questions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, hot-questions

[The formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4789/):

```
(log(Qviews)*4) + ((Qanswers * Qscore)/5) + sum(Ascores)
--------------------------------------------------------
((QageInHours+1) - ((QageInHours - Qupdated)/2)) ^ 1.5
```

What does Qupdated mean in the formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the difference (in hours) between current time and the time the question was last modified (edited, answered, etc - anything that would update `LastActivityDate`).

Comment: As you know, the formula is used to determine hot questions.    What does Qanswers mean in the hot tab but not the week or month tab? Is it mean how many answers were generated in the past 24 hours or how many answers the question totally have? I have the same question about Qscore and Ascores too.

Comment: @xshsinap `Qanswers` is the number of answers on a question, `Qscore` is the question score, `Ascore` is the sum of all answer scores. The only difference between `hot`, `week`, and `month` tabs is the length of time we look at. Right now, hot on SO = last two days. Each variable in the formula is relative to a particular question, not to the date range.

Comment: The length of time you look at maybe mean how old the questions you picked up are. For example, you just only pick up the questions that were asked in the last two days in the hot tab. Am I right? And I want to know how often does the hot, week and month tabs update?

Comment: @xshsinap Yes, that's right. The tabs update frequently. The data is cached for (if I recall right) 5 minutes.