# How are Hot Network Questions selected?

Tags: support, questions, hot-questions

I see lots of Hot Network Questions which don't have lots of votes and views (after becoming hot network question, it gets both lots of votes and views).

How are they selected? Is this purely random or picked by human hands?

Comment: I have a [query in this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250726/158100)  that calculates hotness in SEDE